# How to add a close button in a Atom Panel

Tags: panel, atom-editor

I'm developing a package for `Atom`, I have to show long text in a `Panel`:

```
this.modalPanel = atom.workspace.addBottomPanel({
        item: boxMessage,
        visible: true
      });
```

The panel opens just fine but it's impossible for the user to close this panel, I don't know how to add buttons to the created Panel.